# QlikView iis install without QlikView workbench

Tags: qlikview

My organization does not have QlikView WorkBench license. My question is, what are the limitations I will run into as I start using IIS with QlikView instead of QlikView web server.

Is it necessary to have workbench installed with license to be able to develop a web application using Visual studio to display QlikView files?

Currently we have QlikView Web server(non IIS install). If I migrate to IIS install, I just want to know if I may get stuck without a QlikView workbench.

Searched a lot on the net for this info but in vain, so please give some details. I am well versed with Javascript, Ajax, HTML and so on but not yet used them with QlikView .

Comment: It is not at all necessary to have workbench installed with license to be able to develop Qlikview application. I am a Qlikview developer and I have never used IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions.
There aren't any limitations, using IIS over Qlikview webserver is more of a personal preference, as most Qlikview experts do not have knowledge in IIS, if you are already familiar with IIS it might just give you an advantage in the future.

You do not need a workbench license to use IIS.

Here is a presentation to get started with Qlikview and IIS, although the presentation is of older versions the basics and fundamentals stay the same:
https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-2943